# The CPU Utilization metric for Sagemaker Endpoint is empty

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

In the endpoint dashboard, "monitor" section, for the CPU Utilization metric, it says "No data available. There is no data available" How to make it visualize CPU utilization of the endpoint? The endpoint is up and running. I see invocation metrics, but not the Operational metrics, including CPU utilization.

Comment: Do you have CloudWatch Metrics Permissions added to the execution role attached to the endpoint ?